# Connect to ArcSDE geodatabase over LAN?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am running ArcGIS Server 10, with ArcSDE 10. I have a geodatabase that I would like my colleague to connect to over the LAN at our office. How do I go about doing this? I would prefer a list of simple steps than a link to the ESRI Web Help URL.

Answer (score 5):

This link should help you connect to ArcSDE from ArcCatalog:

> [Connecting to an ArcSDE geodatabase from the Catalog window](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sn0000000n000000.htm)

These are the steps you should follow:

1. Expand the Database Connections node in the Catalog window.
2. Double-click Add Spatial Database Connection. This opens the Spatial Database Connection dialog box.
   Type the name of the server on which the DBMS is installed in the Server text box.
3. Enter the Service name (if you are using the ArcSDE Service, instead of direct connect, just enter the port on which the service is running)
4. Enter text in the database name (if SDE is running on an oracle backend, keep it blank; If it is running on a SQL server backend, enter the name of database)
5. Enter username & password
6. Click on Test connection to make sure that you have entered the correct parameters. If the connection works, press ok to save the connection, otherwise check your inputs.